# Suspend Coroutines's execution for multiple callback update

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I can use suspendCoroutine or suspendCancellableCoroutine to work with callbacks (to convert a callback to a suspend function): but how to send result multiple times the result. Use of flow also didn't work.

```
override suspend fun foo(p0: SomeType): String = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val process = object: CallbackFunction() {
       override fun onData(bytes:Long) {
        // how to post onData which is called multiple times
       }

       override fun onComplete() {
          continuation.resumeWith(Result.success())
       }

       override fun onFailure(exp:Exception) {
          continuation.resumeWithException(exp)
       }

    }

}
```

If I post continuation onData with it will crash as it's already resumed.

Please try to help in this issue.

Comment: According to documentation suspend functions return a single result and can't emit multiple results over time like Flows do. So you should use Flows and call `collect` on it i.e.: `fun getHourlyTemperature(): Flow<HourlyTemperature> = callbackFlow { ... }`.

Comment: Inside the scope you can create a callback and the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suspend function can only return one item, so you need to use a flow.

First, you can create a function that returns a `Flow<Long>` that is simply the stream of sequential Long data.

```
private fun getFooBytes(p0: SomeType): Flow<Long> = callbackFlow {
    val callback = object: CallbackFunction() {
       override fun onData(bytes:Long) {
           trySend(bytes)
       }

       override fun onComplete() {
           channel.close() // complete the flow
       }

       override fun onFailure(exp:Exception) {
           cancel(CancellationException("Callback failed", exp)) // end flow prematurely
       }

    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { // only if registerCallback() isn't thread-safe
        someApi.registerCallback(callback)
    }
    awaitClose {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { // only if unregisterCallback() isn't thread-safe
            someApi.unregisterCallback(callback)
        }
    }
}.buffer(Channel.UNLIMITED) // ensures trySend() will always succeed
```

Based on your comment, you want to cumulate this data into an ever-growing String until it is all received. You can use a `fold` operation to create a continually growing `List<Long>` and then `map` that to Strings.

```
override fun foo(p0: SomeType): Flow<String> =
    getFooBytes(p0) // sequential longs
        .fold(mutableListOf()) { list, value -> list.apply { add(value) } } // cumulative longs
        .map { longs ->
            val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(longs.size * Long.SIZE_BYTES)
            with(byteBuffer.asLongBuffer()) { longs.forEach(::put) }
            // I don't know if this is correct, such as whether it gracefully
            // handles partial code points at the end of the bytes:
            String(
                 byteBuffer.array(),
                 Charsets.UTF_8      // for example
            )
        }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
```

Then in your UI, you can collect this flow to display the growing Strings as they are emitted.

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, Its working but toList() is collected on task completion only, i want it as callback emits so that to update the ui in realtime, now after download only i am getting callback and ui updated any solution?

Comment: Question is updated to show how to produce a Flow of Strings that get bigger as the data comes in. You can collect the flow in the UI layer following standard practice for either Compose or traditional views.